# How to create a centerXProperty in a Rectangle to bind to?

Tags: javafx, properties, binding

I am developing a program for video annotation. Objects seen in a video may be marked as objects of interest and if they are interacting, the user may draw a line between two annotations. On the visible level, bject annotations are basically transparent `Rectangle`s and relations between them are `Line`s. At this point it is easy to compute the center of a rectangle, but I am not able to bind the start and end of a `Line` to the center of the corresponding `Rectangle`. I have tried the following approaches:

Creating two `DoubleBinding`s inside the rectangle class that computes the center x and y:

```
private DoubleBinding centerXBinding = new DoubleBinding() { 
    @Override
    protected double computeValue() {
        return getX() + getWidth() / 2;
    }
};
```

and then bound it to the newly created `Line`:

```
`currentRelation.startXProperty().bind(startShape.centerXBinding());`
```

in the controller…

The result is ok at first, the line start and end points are exactly where I want to haven them, but when a `Rectangle` gets dragged to another position, the line end does not move anywhere!
Does anyone see the problem?

**UPDATE:**

The movement of a `Rectangle` is done by computing an offset and updating the translation values like `translateX`:

```
public class MyRectangle extends Rectangle {

    private double orgSceneX;
    private double orgSceneY;
    private double orgTranslateX;
    private double orgTranslateY;

    private void initEventHandling() {
        this.setOnMousePressed(mousePress -> {
            if (mousePress.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY) {
                orgSceneX = mousePress.getSceneX();
                orgSceneY = mousePress.getSceneY();
                orgTranslateX = ((MyRectangle) mousePress.getSource()).getTranslateX();
                orgTranslateY = ((MyRectangle) mousePress.getSource()).getTranslateY();
                mousePress.consume();
            } else if (mousePress.getButton() == MouseButton.SECONDARY) {
                    System.out.println(LOG_TAG + ": right mouse button PRESS on " + this.getId() + ", event not consumed");
            }
        });

        this.setOnMouseDragged(mouseDrag -> {
            if (mouseDrag.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY) {

                double offsetX = mouseDrag.getSceneX() - orgSceneX;
                double offsetY = mouseDrag.getSceneY() - orgSceneY;
                double updateTranslateX = orgTranslateX + offsetX;
                double updateTranslateY = orgTranslateY + offsetY;
                this.setTranslateX(updateTranslateX);
                this.setTranslateY(updateTranslateY);
                mouseDrag.consume();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your binding needs to invalidate when either the `xProperty` or `widthProperty` are invalidated (so that anything bound to it knows to recompute). You can do this by calling the [`bind` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/DoubleBinding.html#bind-javafx.beans.Observable...-) in the custom binding's constructor:

```
private DoubleBinding centerXBinding = new DoubleBinding() { 

    {
        bind(xProperty(), widthProperty());
    }

    @Override
    protected double computeValue() {
        return getX() + getWidth() / 2;
    }
};
```

Note you can also do

```
private DoubleBinding centerXBinding = xProperty().add(widthProperty().divide(2));
```

The choice between the two is really just a matter of which style you prefer.

Binding to the `x` and `width` properties assumes, obviously, that you are moving the rectangle by changing one or both of those properties. If you are moving the rectangle by some other means (e.g. by changing one of its `translateX` or `translateY` properties, or by altering its list of transformations), then you need to observe the `boundsInParentProperty` instead:

```
private DoubleBinding centerXBinding = new DoubleBinding() {

    {
        bind(boundsInParentProperty());
    }

    @Override
    protected double computeValue() {
        Bounds bounds = getBoundsInParent();
        return (bounds.getMinX() + bounds.getMaxX()) / 2 ;
    }
}
```

This binding will give the x-coordinate of the center of the rectangle in the parent's coordinate system (which is usually the coordinate system you want).

Comment: Well, unfortunately, I am moving the `Rectangle` by `translateX`, so this solution (though correct) is not the one that makes the binding work. Do you know what to do when my movement is done by translation?

Comment: @deHaar This is why it's so frustrating when people post questions that don't include a [MCVE]: there is no guarantee the problem they describe is caused by the code they posted and not by some other code they didn't post (which is the case here). Please update your question. (Or, obviously, change your approach so that you move the rectangle by changing `x`.)

Comment: sorry for being frustrating, I updated the question with the code that does the movement of the `Rectangle`. There are corresponding properties for my solution, so I will change the aproach to a binding with translation values because they are the ones that get uptated. If you know any better approach, please let me know.

Comment: @deHaar See edits to answer. Is there a reason you are translating the rectangle instead of using the (somewhat more obvious) approach of changing its `x` and `y` coordinates?

Comment: No, there isn't… At least none but the fact that it was in a tutorial like that and was working. Yes, adjusting the `x` and `y` coordinates is the most obvious approach (when thinking instead of reading and copy-pasting). Nevertheless, the binding you posted in the updated answer works as desired, thanks a lot.